# как сгенерить key в Keystore на основе полученного извне byte[]/String

Tags: java, android, безопасность, криптография, keystore

Есть AES ключ в виде byte[] полученый с сервера. Нужно создать Key и положить его в Keystore, либо сгенерить ключ уже в KeyStore на основе этого масива.

Альтернативы хранить его в памяти как переменную либо ложить в файл и энкриптить файл уже локальным ключем смотрятся достаточно грусно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немножко неверно понимаете как работает `KeyStore` из `KeyStore` невозможно ни получить ни положить ключ. Ключ можно сгенерировать в нем и он там останется навсегда (вернее материал - байтовый массив ключа)

> Once keys are in the keystore, they can be used for cryptographic operations with the key material remaining non-exportable.

В вашем случае паттерн действий прогера должен быть такой:

1. Сгенерировать в `KeyStore` уникальные ключи (например RSA)
2. Зашифровать полученными ключами ваш ключ от AES полученный от сервера
3. И положить шифрованный ключ в преференсы в виде HEX/Base64 строки

[Примеры здесь](https://medium.com/@ericfu/securely-storing-secrets-in-an-android-application-501f030ae5a3)